# SQL Server to return text if there are transactions with multiple values

Tags: sql-server

I am running a sale query where there could be multiple Order numbers per transaction. If this is the case, I would like the query to return the word "Multiple" in the column and if it only has one order, return the order #.

```
SELECT Distinct TOP 10000 [Store Number]
  ,[Store Name]
  ,[Register Sales Posting Date]
  ,[Transaction Date]
  ,[Register ID]
  ,[Transaction ID]
  ,[Net Sales]
  ,[Tax Exempt Sales]
  ,[Markdown]
  ,[Tax Amount]
  ,[Gross Sales]
  ,[Tax Exempt ID]
  ,CASE
     WHEN COUNT([Customer Order Number])>'1' THEN 'Multiple'
     ELSE[Customer Order Number]
   END
FROM [PropertyTax].[dbo].[SQLAExport]
WHERE [Store Number] = '4920'
  AND [Transaction Date] = '1/14/2011'
GROUP BY 
       [Store Number]
      ,[Store Name]
      ,[Register Sales Posting Date]
      ,[Transaction Date]
      ,[Register ID]
      ,[Transaction ID]
      ,[Net Sales]
      ,[Tax Exempt Sales]
      ,[Markdown]
      ,[Tax Amount]
      ,[Gross Sales]
      ,[Tax Exempt ID]
      ,[Customer Order Number]
```

Comment: What version of SQL server you are using?

Comment: Remove the Case and leave the count.  Then wrap your entire sql with a select, and then use the CASE on the CustomerOrderNumberCount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you can use `count() over (partition by ...)`. If on a lower version you can get the count of orders per transaction (or w/e you're partitioning by) using a `cross apply` for example (see this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8cbf9/1) for examples of both techniques).

Try removing the group by and change the case expression to use a windowed count instead (in this query I assumed that [Transaction ID] was the thing to partition by (that specifies a group), if it's not you might have to change it).

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 
   [Store Number]
  ,[Store Name]
  ,[Register Sales Posting Date]
  ,[Transaction Date]
  ,[Register ID]
  ,[Transaction ID]
  ,[Net Sales]
  ,[Tax Exempt Sales]
  ,[Markdown]
  ,[Tax Amount]
  ,[Gross Sales]
  ,[Tax Exempt ID]
  , CASE WHEN COUNT([Customer Order Number]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Transaction ID]) > 1 
         THEN 'Multiple'
        ELSE [Customer Order Number] 
    END -- if [Customer Order Number] is a number and not a char you need to cast it
FROM [PropertyTax].[dbo].[SQLAExport]
WHERE [Store Number] = '4920'   
  AND [Transaction Date] = '1/14/2011'
```

Also, know that using `top n` without any `order by` clause won't give you a deterministic result, but rather a random selection of `n` rows (which might seem ordered but isn't guaranteed to be). Always include `order by` when you use `top`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I am assuming that I can still add the SELECT DISTINCT to return on line per trans ID.

Comment: @JaredHilburn Yes, adding `distinct` shouldn't matter.